# Iterating arrays in TCL where array names have a numeric suffix

Tags: array, associative-array, tcl

In TCL, I have a few arrays whose names have a numeric suffix
(i.e., whose names end with a number), like below:

```
array set ps0 [ list 0 15.885 1 55.43 1 0.254 2 0.227 3 0.177 ]
array set ps1 [ list 0  6.585 1 56.43 1 0.254 2 0.227 3 0.177 ] 
array set ps2 [ list 0 32.485 1 43.13 1 0.254 2 0.227 3 0.177 ]
```

I need to iterate over these in TCL and get the values,
but, no matter what I do to escape the numeric suffix,
I cannot get both the array and the contents. 
Everything I've tried, such as:

```
ps$i($i)
"ps$i($i)"
```

or even using a set like:

```
set p ps$i
```

...does not work to get the array with the number index. 
I get the error:

```
Original error: can't read "ps": no such variable
```

...for all possible combinations. 
How can I do this (in TCL)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you're trying to build a variable name at runtime, it's a big sign you're Doing It Wrong and should be using a [`dict`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm) instead (Usually easier to work with all around than arrays). In this case, a multi-dimensional dictionary:

```
dict set ps 0 [dict create 0 15.885 1 55.43 1 0.254 2 0.227 3 0.177]
dict set ps 1 [dict create 0 6.585 1 56.43 1 0.254 2 0.227 3 0.177]
dict set ps 2 [dict create 0 32.485 1 43.13 1 0.254 2 0.227 3 0.177]

puts [dict get $ps 1 0] ;# 6.585
dict set ps 1 0 3.14159 ;# Change it to pi

# Print out all the key-value pairs in the ps dict associated with 0
dict for {k v} [dict get $ps 0] {
    puts "$k\t$v"
}
```

---

The [documentation](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M14) for variable substitution says of `$name(index)`:

> *Name* gives the name of an array variable and *index* gives the name of an element within that array. *Name* must contain only letters, digits, underscores, and namespace separators, and may be an empty string. Letters and digits are only the standard ASCII ones (**0–9**, **A–Z** and **a–z**)

so that's part of why things like `ps$i($i)` aren't working for you - there's no variable substitution done in the name. And in that example it's looking for an array variable named `i` anyways.

Comment: ok, this makes a LOT more sense like this.  I am used to high level compiled languages and this caught me off guard as it seemed so trivial.  it seems I have a lot more to learn about the intricacies of TCL and the internal structure of some of these foundational concepts.  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

dicts are clearly the better choice here.

There is a way to get this work with arrays. Use [`upvar`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/upvar.htm) to link the dynamic name to a "temporary" one

```
foreach i {0 1 2} {
    puts "ps$i"
    upvar 0 ps$i tmp
    parray tmp
}
```

```
ps0
tmp(0) = 15.885
tmp(1) = 0.254
tmp(2) = 0.227
tmp(3) = 0.177
ps1
tmp(0) = 6.585
tmp(1) = 0.254
tmp(2) = 0.227
tmp(3) = 0.177
ps2
tmp(0) = 32.485
tmp(1) = 0.254
tmp(2) = 0.227
tmp(3) = 0.177
```

Since the array keys are sequential integers, I'm wondering why you're not using plain lists.

Comment: That is actually what I had been doing a bit yesterday and it seemed to work ok, but not perfectly.  :)  I had something like:  proc getArrayValue {arrayName index} {
    upvar 1 $arrayName array
    if {[info exists array($index)]} {
        return $array($index)
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}. ...this works ok, but the issue was dereferencing in the arrays.  TBH I would like to stay with arrays to speed up the lookup but I also profiled the dictionary perf in TCL and it is ok for a script.  I was having index alignment issues with things like: [getArrayValue $ps_item 0]

Comment: WRT to Lists, it was mostly habit.  I will look now, thank you.  I am dealing with sets that have a range of widths & an array was a way for me to orient myself.  There are simply a LOT of these in the collection & the base names had to be something the source app could serialize when processing w/as few iterations possible.  I'll look at lists.  My issue wrt dictionaries was any risk of lookup costs if there were 3M of these objects & diff lengths.  Even a tree meant some time testing nodes rather than address sequences but I am prepared to accept I could be wrong.